# Visual guides request or dictionary for understanding Coxeter-Dynkin diagram

Tags: polytopes, coxeter-groups, dynkin-diagrams

I've seen there are many types of vertices using in Coxeter-Dynkin type diagram to describe the symmetries and polytopes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_planar_symmetry_groups#Wallpaper_groups

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_symbol

What I've seen in above linkes are
Normal nodes, ringed nodes, hole, ringed hole, dash in hole, pause button, plus in hole, dot in hole, etc.

I understand how the ordinary Coxeter-Dynkin diagram works, but I couldn't reproduce the result when there are other types of vertices.

For example, (0)-3-(0) produces the star hexagon, but I don't know how ringed hole works, and so I couldn't understand why it happens. I guess that (')-3-(') produces the star hexagon, but this just generates the truncated triangle = hexagon.

So, I would like to know the action of such vertices and requests the dictionary or visual guidance to understand such things. Are ther any recommendation?

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter%E2%80%93Dynkin_diagram#Application_with_uniform_polytopes) help?

Comment: @DavidSheard Thanks for the link, but I've already seen the article before and I feel I still don't know how to apply it correctly... the above links are my try to understand the article given. The description of active mirror, inactive mirror, vertices are confusing to me. I can't draw it in myself when the diagram is given.

Comment: I encountered this question when trying to understand Coxeter diagrams myself, and found [this](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2012/07/22/symmetry-and-the-fourth-dimension-part-3/) page describing the geometry with helpful diagrams. I was able to figure out how ringed nodes work when visualizing a cube, truncated cube, cuboctahedron etc. with the website's visualization